# How can I get data from a scale into a web application?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

*If you think I should ask this question elsewhere, please let me know.

**Background:**

I need to build an application for converting weights into piece counts. The weights currently come from scales that are connected to PCs via serial ports. I am replacing PC based applications that connect to the scales via a serial connection. I am considering the feasibility of making the next generation of these applications into a web based solution. However, I do not want to do this if it is not a better solution than building an application that runs on the client. In addition, I do not want to use any sort of browser specific technology (ActiveX).

FYI, we currently run a Windows based environment.

**What I have so far:**

I am currently thinking that I will need some sort of client side “service” to allow the scale data to be retrieved by the web application. I have looked into creating a WCF service for this task and have determined that it would probably work. This would require that the scale be connected to some sort of Windows based computer that is on the network. I would then interface the WCF service (running as a Windows Service on the PC) from an ASP.NET web application running on an IIS web server. This would minimize the footprint on the client and allow us to use a web application.

I am looking for any constructive thoughts and ideas. I am open to reviewing any feasible option that would make this solution as simple and reliable as possible.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? I'm facing the same scenario and was hoping there's a way to avoid installing a service on the client.

Comment: @honeycomb Hello. I did find a solution. I will post it as an answer if I get a few minutes later today.

Comment: @honeycomb Hello again. Sorry for the slow response. I posted a summary  of my findings as an answer. Let me know if you want some more specific details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question per request @honeycomb.

I discovered two viable options for this purpose. Following are high-level overviews of the techniques we leveraged.

1. Develop a **scale reader** to be run on a PC connected to the weigh scale device via an RS-232 connection. This reader will forward any information received from the scale into a database. Combined with technologies like **change notifications** and **server-side push notifications**, this option will allow data from a weigh scale to be pushed into a web page with little effort and no additional cost. (This option has performed well during testing but is not yet in production)
2. Invest in converting weigh scale devices to use ethernet connections and connect them to the network. Use an OPC server with a driver that can connect to the weigh scales you are using to read the data from these devices. Consider [KEPWare's offering](https://www.kepware.com/products/products_ucon.asp) for this purpose. Use KEPWare's tools to forward this data to a database or wherever it is needed. Once again, you can leverage change notifications and server-side push technologies to push this data into web applications in near real-time without polling. (This option is currently working in a critical, production environment)

The second option is probably better in the long-term, but this may vary based on your specific situation. It has some up front costs and would be better suited to new implementations. For my system, I am using the first option because it will ease the transition between the new and old systems.

Note: I am not in any way associated with KEPWare. I am only suggesting their product because it is the only one I am aware of that supports this functionality. I am sure there are other OPC servers that support this type of device.

Comment: Thanks for the solution; I reckon option 1 is best for my requirement right now.